# Scala: Nothing and throw expression

Tags: scala, throw

scala.Nothing is a type with no value of this type.

In scala a 'throw' expression has type Nothing, and also an expression evaluates to a value.

Don't these 2 contradict?

Comment: I think it is important to distinguish `throw expressions has type Nothing` from `throw returns Nothing` did you mean the latter ?

Comment: def error(message: String): Nothing =
throw new RuntimeException(message)
....this code probably means that throw expression has type Nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

No. It's just clumsy wording. On the type level, expressions always evaluate to some type. One of those types is `Nothing`, so-called "bottom type" that sits on the bottom as a subclass of all other types. It's a type without actual values, which means that expressions that resolve into type `Nothing` (such as throw expressions) don't evaluate to a value. This is an exception to the "expression always evaluates to a value" rule. And if Scala were a pure FP language, that rule would hold without exceptions (pun totally intended).

Long answer:

Throwing is not only hard to reason about in functional programming because it produces a side-effect, but it is also hard to reason about in a statically typed language because you can't reason about assigning a type if you have no value. And that's exactly what happens here - instead of resolving into a value, you simply "explode". Thrown exceptions transcend the boundaries of statically typed code by ripping its fabric and creating a portal which allows them to continue their journey in a different dimension.

Poetic notions aside, even though throwing is tricky to reason about in the context of a strongly, statically typed functional programming language such as Scala, it needs to exist (due to Scala being based on the JVM and having an OOP side as well) so it has to somehow play well with the compiler and the type system.

So what we do is, we simply assign such expressions the type `Nothing`. Note that I'm using the word "expression", because normally I would say "assign such values", but here *there is no value*.

Take a look at the following example:

```
def myFunction(i: Int): String = i match {
  case 42 => "Fourty two"
  case _  => throw new Exception("Not fourty two")
}
```

Above function returns a `String`. However, the second pattern matching case throws an exception. Does that resolve into a value of type `String`? No. It doesn't even resolve into a value in the first place! But in order to make such things work in the context of a typed system, we have to assign a type to the whole `throw ...` expression. And in order to make such expressions work everywhere, no matter which type is expected (in the above example it's `String`), we simply make it resolve into a bottom type = `Nothing`.

This means that:

1. Throw statements will compile wherever you put them, which is a requirement of having such statements in the first place (otherwise you might as well just ditch them from the language)
2. Reasoning about throw statements being treated as expressions of type `Nothing` makes sense, because `Nothing` is a type that cannot take any values, and `throw` statement also cannot ever resolve into a value. That's my metaphore from earlier about how it tears up the fabric of the program - you enter a code path that promised to resolve into a `String`, but instead of coming back with a value of type `String`, you instead somehow escape without ever resolving into a value at all. Remember, pure FP language should never allow exceptions to exist in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Is this all handled differently in purely functional languages like Haskell?

Comment: Not really. Haskell is still a Turing-complete language, and thus a partial language. It is possible to write an infinite loop in Haskell, but like every other expression, the infinite loop must evaluate to a value, and it must have a type. You have this with *every* Turing-complete language. Every Turing-complete language has diverging computation that never finishes. What's the value of that?

Comment: Great point. Perhaps I should have emphasized the difference between throwing exceptions and the presence of "has type, but doesn't have value" concept in general. Former simply has no place in a language like Haskell.

Comment: Haskell actually has exceptions. They are considered a design mistake by many.

Comment: Oh, okay. My experience with Haskell is limited to hobby projects only, so I was never exposed to ugly parts of the language. :)

Comment: `Nothing` is a **subtype** not a **subclass** of all other types.

Comment: `Nothing` is by no means the only type without values in Scala. In fact it's trivial to create new ones. Just put `sealed trait Foo` in a file and don't extend it, and voilà you have a type without values.

Comment: True. I didn't mean to insinuate that you cannot create more of them.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few uses of `Nothing` in Scala

1. Express variance in the type parameters (since it is never instantiated, this does make the underlying implementation easier from the type system perspective)
2. A piece code might "return" the type `Nothing` if it never returns. This is the important distinction between `Unit` & `Nothing`, in `Unit` you still return but you return a void value, whereas in the case of `Nothing` you don't actually return. This is in fact the case for exception handling and there are good reasons behind this, passing around the control of the program.. Exception handling is usually implemented using/in a similar fashion to automatic callback insertion(ACI)/continuation passing style (CPS). That is when this code is compiled, there are callbacks inserted into the code for the exception throwing function to pass the control, with some custom stack, to where ever the exception needs to be handled. Borrowing from other languages, if you are interested in how this works, you can look at Scheme's `call/cc`, or Racket's `let/cc` which pretty much simulates exception handling.

That is do some computation -> when you hit an exception, no matter how much more things there are to be computed, bail out, discard everything, go back to the original stack.